# How does HashMap track fields like entrySet

Tags: java

When I read source code of JDK, I found something quite confused me.
That is how does the HashMap track entrySet or values.

Here is the clear() code of HashMap

```
public void clear() {
    Node<K,V>[] tab;
    modCount++;
    if ((tab = table) != null && size > 0) {
        size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i)
            tab[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how does this method control the entrySet. 
As I know, entrySet is cached by the instance of HashMap, but I never found anywhere it changes.

The code upon there is only clear the table. 
Here is some fields of HashMap.

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
    implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {
    transient Node<K, V>[] table;
    transient Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet;

    transient size;
    transient int modCount;
    int threshold;
    final float loadFactor;

    // other part
}
```

**I don't understand here. Since clear method only changes the table, how does it effects the entrySet.**

> I use JUnit to test my thinking. The HashMap's entrySet is empty after I call the clear() method.

Here is the entrySet() code below

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
    return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
}
```

if entrySet is not null, it returns the cached entrySet, but clear() method never changes cached entrySet. How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

`entrySet()` is just a view. There's nothing in it, except (implicitly) a reference to the `HashMap`. It doesn't create a second data structure, the `Set` methods just access the map directly.

See the private [`HashMap.EntrySet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.EntrySet) class for the way it's implemented. It's an inner class, so it can see the enclosing `HashMap` instance (the object that "owns" it).

Here's a very simple example which works exactly the same way:

```
interface Foo {
    void setFizz(int fizz);
    int getFizz();
}

interface Bar {
    void setBazz(int bazz);
    int getBazz();

    // returns a view of this Bar as if it were a Foo
    Foo asFoo();
}

class BarImpl implements Bar {
    int bazz;

    @Override
    public int setBazz(int bazz) {
        this.bazz = bazz;
    }
    @Override
    public int getBazz() {
        return this.bazz;
    }

    @Override
    public Foo asFoo() {
        return new Foo() {
            @Override
            public int setFizz(int fizz) {
                BarImpl.this.bazz = fizz;
            }
            @Override
            public int getFizz() {
                return BarImpl.this.bazz;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

There is only ever a single `int`, calling `asFoo()` just lets us access the `Bar` as if it were a `Foo`.

Comment: I know it's a inner class. I mean the clear() method does not change the entrySet, but it does effect the entrySet() returns. From the entrySet() code we know it return the entrySet field. How does it works?

Comment: *"clear() method does not change the entrySet"* `entrySet` has nothing to change. It has nothing in it. There is only the map, which the `entrySet` accesses directly.

Comment: I don't understand. When I am testing, I put some val into the map, map.entrySet() has value, As you said it has nothing in it, why it has value after I put some val in it.

Comment: I think I understand what you said. Thanks so much, it confused me a lot. Thanks.